# How come my python code doesn't work?

Tags: python, http, python-imaging-library

```
def getSize(f):
    print StringIO(f)
    im = Image.open(StringIO(f))
    size = im.size[0], im.size[1]
    return size

def download(source_url, g = False, correct_url = True):
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)
        agents = ['Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0)','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 5.1)','Microsoft Internet Explorer/4.0b1 (Windows 95)','Opera/8.00 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)']
        ree = urllib2.Request(source_url)
        ree.add_header('User-Agent',random.choice(agents))
        ree.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')
        opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        h = opener.open(ree).read()
        if g:
            compressedstream = StringIO(h)
            gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressedstream)
            data = gzipper.read()
            return data
        else:
            return h
    except Exception, e:
        return ""



pic = download("http://media2.ct.yelpcdn.com/photo/2MdauidaMUazuew2h0pdgQ/l")
s = getSize(pic)
```

When I do this, there is an error:

```
print StringIO(f)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1980, in open
raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

Comment: You're just discarding any useful exceptions that download() will throw - Image.open() might be trying to read "" being returned by download(), which would explain the current error you're receiving. If you remove that try..catch block, do you receive any more informative errors?

Comment: retagged to remove django tag - no dependency on django here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `Accept-Encoding` states `gzip` so you're probably getting a gzipped image.

I just tried your code with your gzip decompression on and it works without any problems.

```
    pic = download("http://media2.ct.yelpcdn.com/photo/2MdauidaMUazuew2h0pdgQ/l", g=True)
    s = getSize(pic)
```

So does changing your `'Accept-Encoding'` from `'gzip'` to `'image.*'`

```
    ree.add_header('User-Agent',random.choice(agents))
    ree.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'image.*')
```

---

Part 2:

You could always ask for `gzip` and wrap with try/except here to return the data unaltered if gzip complains.

```
    try:
        compressedstream = StringIO(h)
        gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressedstream)
        data = gzipper.read()
        return data
    except IOError: # not gzip
        return h
```

Comment: how do I change a download function that takes care of all downloads, reglardless of gzip or image?

Comment: I suppose you could wrap the gzip function in a try / except block, but a server should not be sending you a content type that's not in your accept-encoding. Since it sounds extremely unlikely, if you want to do this I would test if the response is gzipped AFTER you try to open it with PIL.